# Triangular wave to sawtooth wave

Tags: waveform, circuits, sawtooth-waveform

wanted to design a sweeper circuit to change a triangular wave into sawtooth wave. Is there a schematic for this to design a circuit?

Comment: You must learn to define specs before any design. That can change everything.  Slew rate? deadtime? f ranges? polarity, Vmin-max, tuneable for anything? or just use the sawtooth sweep on the back of an old scope  1~ 50 Hz 11V https://tinyurl.com/y4gzdm7k

Answer (score 1):

If you mean gradually change triangle form to sawtooth, with same amplitude/frequency, then I think a variation on the classic op-amp triangle wave circuit can be a starting point, but it distorts the frequency. You could replace R2 with a bridge and two current sources?

[image]

Here I_1 controls amplitude, V_IN controls level.

For a symmetrical wave, V_MID is mid supply, but you can vary V_MID to change ratio of rise rate to fall rate. Here's a [falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3AWAnC1b0DZwA5oCYB2bJMAVnOwzAQNLxAMhFJAQGYAoAQ3D2xDx4EA0lkHCkzKOHjwB0JKUgJZqyBDzRqCUox1gMOtgWFg13Vm3rjW2Jjf4smZ1eHwYhSIqTbYlSDAI3PA9kdHQgl1kOAHdLa0h+X2E8RKhY+IEVEGSspkgM3NSk7FMMfMLS8HLWA2qKuNyDJjY6evSAJwFsfmactr6mFXgOAGNarD6EQ3b7aCU1RYQAUwBaINWYHrYMUjAwImxqDwwsGDgwDOmypj36QYy79qebAriXoVt7T7fmMHuak99vRfkD-t1euDfjZgbxISCMv94XDZoi+O0kQI0gUAJYgOwgGZ9Gb5WDwcIU1AZITOGp4USouL0yZ0hmvakMvp8Xo1AqpIIfYSiewM4QANQA9gBXAAuHAAJuAkAD7NkuSB5csAGZcKUAGzlADdbEr6Aheuj8qxbtJSaQOABzFHclFsZS2xE1InKwnCX5gH3elXpOKYl3miEhk0Bs38F0FRUxjE1dWanX6uWJlMp9Gp7W6g0ZAkzCMkq78EsW-j+9E06p5ATlyOrOrxjItsQ9EAdgQEBFxHuV32Ng7CHuEAECT4QYakgjGLAAGQAomLl4v2620j2DmcOF0dwQsDuoTI4JvJuDB36OKOp6ZwRPwOCNLIoNBpspFqo2CAAIIALIAAqLgAkgAKgAqgAIsuHJYAEIhYAS0IMgSLoodSXboV2sIFHeqwzMU3ZEimzByDA9L0iAADqf5rqsADKAASf5AXBA5EggY4zGWnHCDM15RoRKTbkRXa-CJzathJ7YEru3awgpklKUeingmwOzCbCmlYLkulRvpWlFNkBQSgIEB1EMxBDO+ED2BZOQcEAA) to play with.